# Gets the error "NameError: name 'user' is not defined" when code is run

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I run my code through I get an the error "NameError: name 'user' is not defined". I don't know what to change/add to fix this error.

I've tried to make different versions of the code and none of them worked. This one does looks like it would do what I want, but 'user' is not defined.

```
import random
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Game
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import datetime
from discord.utils import get
import time

TOKEN = ''

bot = Bot(command_prefix='?')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Beep beep')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="with Roles"))
    print('------')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = bot.get_channel('484471901142384644')
    role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="test")
    message = await bot.send_message(channel, "React to me!")
    while True:
        reaction = await bot.wait_for_reaction(emoji=":thumbsup:", message=message)
        await bot.add_roles(reaction.message.author, role)
bot.run("")
```

I would like to have the bot show a message then when I react with :thumbsup: I get the testing role 'test'. Instead when I run I get the error "NameError: name 'user' is not defined" as stated numerous times above. An explanation of why this does not work would be nice. Also the way to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Well user is indeed not defined. Where is it supposed to be coming from? Did you perhaps mean `bot.user.server.roles`?

Comment: `bot.user` will be a `User` object, and not have a `server`.  Use `channel.server` instead.